# What do these characters painting mean?

Tags: translation

I tried to translate these characters but I´m not sure. Am I right?

I have more difficulties for the last 3.

勁直凌霄节傾斜帶兩枝 戊子初春 X子X

It could be something like that, no?

[image]Straight slanting section with two branches
Spring of the Wuzhi year (Which one?)
XXX?

Could you help me?

Be indulgent. I´m a beginner ;-)

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the text is:

> 勁直凌霄節．傾斜帶雨枝
>
> 戊子初春　柳子谷

i've impression that it's an inscription of a painting. the painter asked mr 柳子谷 to write it. the time is 戊子年, 2008-60i (2008, 1948, . . .), 初春 is the first month of spring.

the painting would be about bamboo (竹).

節 means  bamboo joint (竹節). the metaphor is:

bamboo --> nobleman (君子)

勁直 ~ strong and upright, straightly without branch

凌霄 ~ a bamboo grow upwards, towards the sky

at the same time, bamboo is also flexible, that in adverse situation, like downpour, cats and dogs (--> 帶雨), it can be bent (--> 傾斜), [枝] without breaking.

so, bamboo grow skywards straightly, with flexibility to bent in adverse situation.

--> nobleman (君子) always strive for good moral and behaviour, would make compromise, in case.

Answer (score 2):

The last 3 characters are 柳子谷, an artist's name and the ninth character is 雨. But I am not quite confident about the meanings.

EDIT:

Ah I see: 凌霄 is 凌霄花, 凌霄带雨 is a metaphor for adamancy and bravery.

EDIT 2:

See the comments below (*°∀°)=3

Comment: The original passage is 勁直凌寒節，傾斜帶雨枝

Comment: @droooze Ah, But here it is obviously 霄...

Comment: Yep, this is a variation on that by the artist I think.

Comment: @droooze Quite true. But 劲节 is solely used for eulogy for bamboo, so I incline to regard it a mistake.

Comment: It is written in 戊子年初春 by 柳子谷， I think the topic is 竹子 bamboo